# Redirect to new tab with masking url nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, web, redirect

Im doing nodeJS backend, when front-end call my API, i want to redirect users to new tab, masking url of redirect with my own url, explaining my problem:

It's two step problem, i can solve it one by one but not both together.

For redirect masking url i can:

```
if(url){
request(url).pipe(res);
}
```

For redirect opening url on new tab:

```
open(url, function (err) {
    if ( err ) throw err;    
});
```

I tried it but doesnt work

```
open(request(url).pipe(res), function (err) {
        if ( err ) throw err;    
    });
```

anyone know how to do it?

What i need?

Redirect user to new tab, where him will see url content, but masking url with my url

I need this for downloading too

Comment: Your example code is a bit confusing as you seem to be mixing client side and server side code together as window.open is a browser function whereas piping is in NodeJS. Needs more explanation. If you did serve a different webpage from your own backend you could well end up with CORS errors if the webpage you masked tried to make AJAX calls to its own backend. Might be safer to just use an iframe.

Comment: If i use iframe, user can see url of file? i make pipes cause user cant see real url, just see my url

Comment: They will be able to see URL if they inspect/view source of the page but not in the address bar which will show your website. You will get CORS issues if you pipe it unless its mostly a simple static page. I can possibly show you how to pipe it if you show more of your code, what's server side and what's client side and make it clear what libraries you are using.

Comment: url to pipe its firebase url, so yes, its static, i want pipe it to my server cause i want mask it to client, what do u need to see about server? I dont know what i need on client or on server side, im new on web dev.
So i ve static url to pipe on mi own server, and i want show file to client, without let client posibility to take this file or url file, if u know another way to do this, i can take it too, thanks for your time @jcbdrn

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fetching the content from the url you want to mask and then displaying it?

```js
fetch("https://example.com").then(function(response) {
  const ContentType = response.headers.get("Content-Type");
  // Your code here to display the content and set the Content-Type header to the fetched url's Content-Type header.
});
```

I don't understand the new tab part.

Comment: What do you mean on display the content?

Answer (score 0):

Being able to change the url of some existing web page would be a major security issue....

You can however have the backend fetch the content and serve that from your own url. That technique looks similar of creating a reverse proxy.